# Strangely equals returns always false also if the values seems match

Tags: java

I have this methods

getParam

```
public int getParam(String paramName){

    if(paramName.equals("Balls and net")){
        expressionParam=1;
    }
    else if(paramName.equals("Balls and bat")){
        expressionParam=2;
    }
    else if(paramName.equals("Without balls")){
        expressionParam=3;
    }
    else if(paramName.equals("Team Sport")){
        expressionParam=4;
    }
    else{
        expressionParam=-1;
    }

    return expressionParam;
}
```

but for some strange reason the equals in the if conditions returns always false and the method consequentially returns always -1

I invoke this method in the follow button listener

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("    OK   ");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Object[][] matrix=(((MyTableModel) table.getModel()).getDatamatrix());
                     List<Expression> list=new LinkedList<Expression>(); 
                     for (int i = 0; i <elem; i++){
                         Expression e=new Expression(getSport((matrix[i][0]).toString()), getParam((matrix[i][1]).toString()), getSport((matrix[i][2]).toString()));
                         list.add(v); 


             }catch...
```

and with a println I have verified that the values passed to getParams match.

So what is wrong with this method??

Comment: `equals` is case sensitive. You might want to consider using `equalsIgnoreCase` if that's the problem.

Comment: Just a small note: You don't have to use the intermediate variable `expressionParam`. You can just `return x` in place of assigning the variable each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have trailing or leading whitespaces. `trim()` first:

```
public int getParam(String rawParamName){
  final String paramName = rawParamName.trim();

  if(paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("Balls and net")){
  //...
```

Also watch out for character case. `Team sport` will actually return `-1`. Consider using`equalsIgnoreCase()` instead.

Finally you might have different number or type of white spaces, e.g. two spaces or tab between character. This requires a little bit more work.

Finally if you want to be extra flexible consider using [levenshtein distance](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: OP should really redesign his solution so the program logic doesn't depend on human-readable strings.

Answer (score 2):

- `.trim()` before comparison
- `.equalsIgnoreCase(..)`

=>

```
if (paramName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("..")) { .. }
```

Comment: could you give me more details... where should I use `trim()`?
(however the case are the same)

Comment: `paramName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(..)`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the above, but with the corrected method:

```
public int getParam(String paramName){
    String param = paramName.trim();
    if(param.equalsIgnoreCaseIgnoreCase("Balls and net")){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(param.equalsIgnoreCase("Balls and bat")){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(param.equalsIgnoreCase("Without balls")){
        return 3;
    }
    else if(param.equalsIgnoreCase("Team Sport")){
        return 4;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It always helps to remember that equals is case sensitive. equalsIgnoreCase is the alternative to this.
This was a very common mistake I made when I was a beginner at java.

you can also use contains(), but remember to be careful with what you are comparing your string to with this method.